# Arrange/Act/Assert pattern using PHPSpec

Tags: php, phpspec

I'm trying to follow the AAA pattern to write specifications to `ClassA`. This class has dependency with `ClassB` that will interact with `ClassA` as follow:

```php
class ClassA
{
    private $objB;

    public function __construct(ClassB $objB) 
    {
        $this->objB = $objB;
    }

    public function doSomething($arg)
    {
        $val1 = $this->objB->someMethod($arg);

        // do something with variable $val1

        $this->objB->otherMethodCall();  
    }
}
```

And its specification:

```php
class ClassASpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(ClassB $objB)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($objB);
    }

    function it_should_do_something_cool(ClassB $objB)
    {
        // Arrange
        $objB->someMethod(10)->willReturn(...);

        // Act
        $this->doSomething(10);

        // Assert
        $objB->otherMethodCall()->shouldHaveBeenCalled();
    }
}
```

When I run this specification I got an error saying that method `ClassB::otherMethodCall()` was not expected to be called, only `ClassB::someMethod()` was expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this assertion

```
// Arrange
$objB->someMethod(10)->willReturn(...);
```

Your double is a mock and, so, is treated as a mock (no `shouldHaveBeen` but only `shouldBe`)

Here

```
// Assert
$objB->otherMethodCall()->shouldHaveBeenCalled();
```

You are treating your object as it is a spy, that's not the case.

Since your double is a mock, you should modify your code as follows

```
// Arrange
$objB->someMethod(10)->willReturn(...);

// Assert
$objB->otherMethodCall()->shouldBeCalled();

// Act
$this->doSomething(10);
```

To know the difference between mocks, spies and stubs, please read [prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy#mocks) and [phpspec](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/manual/prophet-objects.html) documentation

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto. I'll modify the code as you suggest. So, it isn't possible to write AAA in the original order when using mocks e spies, write? What I should do is to write Arrange, Assert, Act and Assert in case to verify the return of Act.

Comment: @TalesSantos I don't know that particular strategy but are you sure that order matters? because, at least in phpspec and as far as I know, a double could not be spy and mock at the same time as they are checked  before (mocks) or after (spies) method execution

Comment: technically the order doesn't matters, but I think that arrange, act and assert is better keep the specifications organized. Anyway, your answer helped me to understand the difference between mocks and spies. Thanks a lot.